# How to set ruler measurements in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, grids, configuration

New to Inkscape and I just noticed that I can change the grid units. But can I also change the ruler units, If so, how?

Answer (score 22):

Click on the **File menu**, then go down to **Document Properties**. On first tab (called Page) you can set the default unit there and that'll change the ruler measurements.

[image: Inkscape default units]

Comment: this doesn't affect the measure tool units; it always seems to use mm

Answer (score 3):

There are bugs with Inkscape's ruler handling. The dimensions on the ruler will not change in some cases (related to the viewbox).

Start with a new file (rather than opening an old file), and then copy and paste your objects into the new file.

See the [Ruler units not saved](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1667694) bug.